# web view url goes to browser .how to do avoid and open in same web view?

Tags: android, webview

here my code...am already implemented **WebViewClient**  concept.it works well in web view..In my App have content saring via fb,twitter,g+,,,fb also login and open in webview...but when am click share to fb icon in my app after that all process will work on browser..but i want all process in webview only...

**oncreate**

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.setClickable(true);
webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
     ...
} else {
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
}

webView.loadUrl("www.example.com.");
```

**WebViewClient**

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myerrorpage.html");
    }

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must **override** your **shouldOverrideUrlLoading()** method in WebViewClient class and following code

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
        // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
        return false;
    }
    // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

Go through [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use a if clause in your shouldOverrideUrlLoading method that returns false;
Example from [Building web apps in web views](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

`if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
    }`

Comment: return false means what will happen? all url loads only webview?

Comment: if you set the string in the .equals() method to the server name then all the url that have that server in their content will be opened with the webview. However, you can limit the number of pages to be handled by the webview if you insert a custom url. Here is a more detailed tutorial: [WebView tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/android/android-web-apps-using-android-webview.html)